# pam_script get output of previous module

Tags: bash, pam

How can I get a previous modules output with pam_script?

So if I were to stick a pam_script between pam_unix and pam_deny I could perform some action if authentication failed?

Edit: Apparently, if you change the `[success=1]` to `[success=2]` pam will skip an extra line.

This means I can put one script before pam_deny and up the number at success, then one script after pam_deny for correct authentication.

I still need to know how to use two different scripts though. How do I pass the exact script to use to pam_script.so?

Original:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
auth    required            pam_permit.so
auth    optional            pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
auth    optional            pam_cap.so
```

Modified:

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [default=ignore]            pam_script.so # What goes here?
auth    requisite                   pam_deny.so
auth    [default=ignore]            pam_script.so # And what goes here?
auth    required                    pam_permit.so
auth    optional                    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
auth    optional                    pam_cap.so
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pam_script takes options, so...

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    [default=ignore]            pam_script.so incorrect
auth    requisite                   pam_deny.so
auth    [default=ignore]            pam_script.so correct
auth    required                    pam_permit.so
auth    optional                    pam_ecryptfs.so unwrap
auth    optional                    pam_cap.so
```

And in `/usr/share/libpam-script/pam_script_auth`:

```
#!/bin/bash
$1
# rest of script
```